# Only integer should be added from random in php

Tags: php

I'm working out with php and now I'm facing a problem

My php code is:

```
<?php
    $random= rand (1,5)."Boys";     
    $random2= rand (1,5)."Girls";       
    $random3=$random.$random2;
    imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 10,20, $white, $font_path, $random);
    imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 100,200, $white, $font_path, $random2);
    imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 275, 50, $white, $font_path,$random3);
?>
```

I have not given the full coding but I'll explain you the concept that I'm getting random number and a fixed text with it like boys or girls now In `$random3` I only want to show sum of the integer which is randomly given by the `$random` and `$random2` so help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

some editing is needed in your php file.

```
<?php
$random= rand (1,5)."Boys";     
$random2= rand (1,5)."Girls";       
$random3=($random+$random2);
imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 10,20, $white, $font_path, $random);
imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 100,200, $white, $font_path, $random2);
imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 275, 50, $white, $font_path,$random3);
?>
```

Now it will work fine. I have corrected it.